# RabbitMQ app install - /usr/bin/env: escript: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, escript

I'm attempting to build a chat app built in `rabbitmq` from https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmq-chat but ran into this problem when doing a `make`:

```
...
inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_msg_store_index.beam  
/usr/bin/env: escript: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: get-deps: not found
make: *** [deps] Error 127
```

Any idea how to fix this?

The full output:

```
make
mkdir deps;
wget http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/v2.4.1/amqp_client-2.4.1.ez
--2015-03-18 14:54:55--  http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/v2.4.1/amqp_client-2.4.1.ez
Resolving www.rabbitmq.com (www.rabbitmq.com)... 192.240.153.117
Connecting to www.rabbitmq.com (www.rabbitmq.com)|192.240.153.117|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 155938 (152K) [application/andrew-inset]
Saving to: ‘amqp_client-2.4.1.ez’

100%[================================================================================================================>] 155,938      299KB/s   in 0.5s   

2015-03-18 14:54:56 (299 KB/s) - ‘amqp_client-2.4.1.ez’ saved [155938/155938]

wget http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/v2.4.1/rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez
--2015-03-18 14:54:56--  http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/v2.4.1/rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez
Resolving www.rabbitmq.com (www.rabbitmq.com)... 192.240.153.117
Connecting to www.rabbitmq.com (www.rabbitmq.com)|192.240.153.117|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 356609 (348K) [application/andrew-inset]
Saving to: ‘rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez’

100%[================================================================================================================>] 356,609      601KB/s   in 0.6s   

2015-03-18 14:54:56 (601 KB/s) - ‘rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez’ saved [356609/356609]

unzip -d deps amqp_client-2.4.1.ez
Archive:  amqp_client-2.4.1.ez
   creating: deps/amqp_client/
   creating: deps/amqp_client/include/
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl  
   creating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_connection.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_channel.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_connection_sup.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_channel_sup_sup.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_connection_type_sup.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_network_connection.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_channel_sup.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_main_reader.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_auth_mechanisms.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_sup.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_channels_manager.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_rpc_server.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_direct_connection.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_gen_connection.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_client.beam  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_client.app  
  inflating: deps/amqp_client/ebin/amqp_rpc_client.beam  
unzip -d deps rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez
Archive:  rabbit_common-2.4.1.ez
   creating: deps/rabbit_common/
   creating: deps/rabbit_common/include/
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_auth_backend_spec.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_backing_queue_spec.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_exchange_type_spec.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_msg_store_index.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_msg_store.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/gm_specs.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_framing.hrl  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_auth_mechanism_spec.hrl  
   creating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_basic.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_command_assembler.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_8.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_reader.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_binary_parser.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_heartbeat.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_channel.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_net.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_binary_generator.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_queue_collector.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/supervisor2.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_auth_backend.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_misc.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_writer.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_exchange_type.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_backing_queue.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_auth_mechanism.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_common.app  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_amqqueue.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/gen_server2.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.beam  
  inflating: deps/rabbit_common/ebin/rabbit_msg_store_index.beam  
/usr/bin/env: escript: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: get-deps: not found
make: *** [deps] Error 127
```

Answer (score 0):

`escript` is for Erlang scripting support, which RabbitMQ uses internally.

Install `erlang-base` or a similar package for non-Debian operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

That project is quite old and unmaintained. Use it as an idea of how things can be done, but today I wouldn't recommend to use it in production. It even uses misultin which is not maintained anymore.

Comment: What are the alternatives?